# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 in Xcode 7.1

Tags: xcode, mobile, unity-game-engine, vuforia, armv7

I'm making a game with Vuforia and an Unity plugin called Mobile Movie Textures. When I try to build my Xcode project it all goes well until it starts linking. I get a bunch of errors all from the same library saying that it doesn't recognize symbols.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_oc_idct8x8_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_frag_recon_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_idct8x8_1_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_frag_recon_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_frag_recon_intra_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_frag_recon_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_pack_read1_arm", referenced from:
      _th_decode_packetin in libtheorawrapper.a(decode.o)
      _oc_huff_tree_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(huffdec.o)
      _oc_quant_params_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(dequant.o)
  "_oc_frag_recon_inter2_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_frag_recon_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_frag_copy_list_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_frag_recon_inter_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_frag_recon_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_loop_filter_frag_rows_arm", referenced from:
      _oc_state_accel_init_arm in libtheorawrapper.a(armstate.o)
  "_oc_huff_token_decode_arm", referenced from:
      _th_decode_packetin in libtheorawrapper.a(decode.o)
      _oc_sb_run_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(decode.o)
  "_oc_pack_read_arm", referenced from:
      _th_decode_packetin in libtheorawrapper.a(decode.o)
      _oc_sb_run_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(decode.o)
      _th_decode_headerin in libtheorawrapper.a(decinfo.o)
      _oc_unpack_length in libtheorawrapper.a(decinfo.o)
      _oc_huff_tree_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(huffdec.o)
      _oc_quant_params_unpack in libtheorawrapper.a(dequant.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I could just make the devices with an armv7 arch incompatible but they make up 55% of the dutch market.

I don't know how to fix this, can any of you figure it out?

Comment: Set build active architecture to NO

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it doens't work. I still have the same error.

Comment: change settings in unity build settings. i do not remember the exact name but probably you are building your app for only 'x64', set it to 'Universal'

Comment: Thanks, but it's set to universal.

Answer (score 1):

The library libtheorawrapper.a in the current version of the plugin is broken and does not contains all of the needed symbols.

If you want to use the plugin you will have to recompile the library.
To do that you need to checkout [this repository](https://github.com/dantreble/MobileMovieTexture/)
.

Then edit this file:
MMTPlugin/build/XCode/theorawrapper.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
an replace on line 134 and 144

```
/Users/dan/Documents/MobileMovieTexture/
```

with the path you cloned the repo (eg.):

```
/Users/MyUser/Code/git/MobileMovieTexture
```

You can then open that project with XCode and recompile the library.

The resulting file will be placed at:

```
MMTUnity/Assets/Plugins/iOS/libtheorawrapper.a
```

you should copy that file to your unity plugin folder:

```
Assets/Plugins/iOS/libtheorawrapper.a
```

Comment: it took quite some time to get this to work, but it did work, and looking on the plugin it does not seem like it will be updated with the fix, so if anyone else needs the library file that works, you can get it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp8u9ggzw6xxvit/libtheorawrapper.a?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue this morning, it's a problem with the latest version of the MMT plugin: basically, the Assets/Plugins/iOS/libtheorawrapper.a file does not contain everything it should for the armv7 architecture. I replaced it with the same file from the previous version of the plugin (which, fortunately, I had in another project), and everything builds and links again.

As a side note, that file went from about 300KB before to 1.8MB in the latest version, this too seems kind of wrong to me.

I'm about to email the developer about those problems, but feel free to do it too.

Comment: Could you send me that library file? You'd save my skin

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today and it seems that more people do as well.

I succeeded in fixing the library file so that it now works. Just replace it with the one in the Unity/plugins/ios folder

here is a link to download it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp8u9ggzw6xxvit/libtheorawrapper.a?dl=0